# Derivative of inverse function (proof)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-explanation, inverse-function

In class the other day we proved the following theorem regarding the derivative of an invertible, differentiable function $f$:

**Theorem**

Assume that $f \colon D \to V$ is a bijection, $x_0\in D$, $y_0=f(x_0)$, $f'(x_0) \neq 0$ exists and that $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $y_0$. Then the derivative $(f^{-1})'(y_0)$ exists and $(f^{-1})'(y_0) = \frac{1}{f'(x_0)}.$

**Proof**

Consider the difference quotient
\begin{equation*} 
\frac{f^{-1}(y_0+k)-f^{-1}(y_0)}{k}. 
\end{equation*}

Set $h = f^{-1}(y_0+k)-f^{-1}(y_0)$ so that $f^{-1}(y_0+k) = x_0+h$. We then have $f(f^{-1}(y_0+k)) = y_0+k = f(x_0+h)$.

From this we obtain

\begin{equation}
k = f(x_0+h)-y_0 = f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)
\end{equation}

and so

\begin{equation*}
\frac{f^{-1}(y_0+k)-f^{-1}(y_0)}{k} = \frac{h}{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)} \to \frac{1}{f'(x_0)} \text{ when } k\to0.
\end{equation*}

---

What confuses me is why we can assume that $f^{-1}(y_0+k)$ exists for sufficiently small $k$, i.e. that $y_0$ is an inner point of $V$. I can't seem to wrap my head around why. I know that since we assume that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, we implicitly assume that $x_0$ is an interior point of $D$. I also know that since $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, $f$ is also continuous at $x_0$. Does this somehow imply that $y_0 = f(x_0)$ is an interior point of $V$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f'(x_0)>0$. Then, in some interval $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, you have$$x<x_0\implies f(x)<f(x_0)=y_0\text{ and }x>x_0\implies f(x)>f(x_0)=y_0.$$Since $f\bigl((x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\bigr)$ is an interval (since $f$ is continuous), it follows that, yes, $y_0$ is an interior point of $f\bigl((x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\bigr)$ and therefore an interior point of $f(D)$ and therefore an interior point of $V$.

The case in which $f'(x_0)<0$ is similar.

Comment: How come $f'(x_0) >0 $ implies that $f$ is strictly growing in some interval $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$? Also, since I say that $f \colon D \to V$ is a bijection, I mean that $V$ is indeed the image of $D$ under $f$, i.e. $f(D) = V$.

Comment: I did **not** claim that $f$ is strictly increasing in some interval $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$. What I claimed was that, in some interval $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, we have $x<x_0\implies f(x)<f(x_0)$ and $x>x_0\implies f(x)>f(x_0)$. This follows from that fact that$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}>0.$$